# Переформулировать тревогу о вопросе не на русском языке

Tags: предложение, тревоги

Сегодня отмечал вопрос на английском языке и заметил вот что:

[image: Скрин с проблемой]

> - Вопрос закрыт, так как на [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Как можно увидеть, есть несколько заметных отличий от прочих вариантов:

- `Вопрос закрыт, ...` — он как бы ещё не закрыт. Забыли мягкий знак?
- Короткое описание по сравнению с другими (`явно не по теме` не в счёт)
- В принципе отличается формулировка
- Нет выделения сути жирным

P.S.: к тому же, не совсем корректно отсылать на английский сайт португальца/испанца (у них свои есть).

Предлагаю устроить голосование за новую формулировку.

Comment: данный текст будет показан в плашке _после_ закрытия вопроса

Comment: @Grundy хорошо, но это как бы видно и при постановке тревоги

Comment: Это закрывающему показывают, что будет показано автору вопроса.

Answer (score 7):

В текущем виде формулировка действительно смущает. Более того, она не согласуется с остальными (под)причинами закрытия **"не по теме"**. Не суть важно, что этот текст будет показан на вопросе **после** его закрытия. Проблема в том, что в упомянутом окне идёт лишь установка тревоги, а стало быть утверждение о том, что **"вопрос закрыт"** не является корректным. Предлагаю убрать несколько слов с начала и оставить так:

> На [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Здесь ещё, кстати, присутствует одно предположение, что вопрос задан на английском. Часто это действительно так, но встречаются варианты и украинского языка, например. Поэтому в более педантичном варианте упоминать enSO не совсем корректно.

P.S. сначала я не прочитал P.S. автора :)

Answer (score 2):

Мне нравится [формулировка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7091/213987) @alexolut, но мне кажется, что я могу предложить ещё лучше вариант.

Из моего опыта, большинство вопросов, задаваемых не на русском языке - это вопросы на английском (скажем, 90%) и ещё 10% вопросов задаются на украинском языке.

Давайте переставим порядок: alexolut сначала просит перевести вопрос, а потом идти на SOen, я предлагаю сделать наоборот: сначала отправить на SOen, а если автор понимает, что его вопрос не подходит для SOen (текст на украинском) мы рекомендуем перевести вопрос на русский:

> На [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/) или переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык.

Answer (score 1):

> На [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только **на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или опубликуйте его в другом сообществе Stack Overflow на соответствующем ему языке: [английском](https://stackoverflow.com/), [португальском](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [испанском](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) или [японском](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/).

Самую малость напрягает, что строку придётся обновлять по мере возникнвения  (или, не дай Б-же, исчезновения) других сообществ SO, но это событие очень редкое, да и некоторое отставание этого списка относительно безвредно: я практически уверен, что всех авторов вопросов, закрытых по этой причине, ничего кроме enSO и ruSO не интересует.

PS: языки перечислены в порядке [убывания трафика](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-traffic), чтобы читатель статистически быстрее находил нужное ему сообщество при последовательном прочтении.

Comment: Ни разу не видел у нас вопросов на нерусском языке, кроме английского. Теоретически идея кажется хорошей, но было бы классно, если бы это подтверждалось убедительной статистикой.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я видел. На украинском. Неоднократно. Правда, Stack Overflow на украинском не существует и в обозримом будущем я бы не ожидал его появления.

Comment: Охотно верю. Но рекомендации испанского, португальского и япоского сообществ товарищу, которому хочется спрашивать на украинском, не помогут.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov почему же, помогут. Дадут знать, что на украинском его вопрос задать во всей сети Stack Exchange **негде** и придётся переводить или решать проблему другими способами / публиковать на других платформах.

Comment: Не хочу голосовать за этот вариант. Ну зачем нам португальский и прочие редкие языки? По факту, 90% вопросов на английском задаётся, ещё 10% - на украинском. Давайте исходить из реалий сегодняшнего дня.

Comment: @D-side С этой мыслью не согласен. То что в списке не приведено какого-то локализованного сообщества не значит, что его не существует. А если примут [вариант alexolut](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7091/220571) то что, из этого следует, что ruSO — едиственный локализованный вариант?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov а вот этот инвариант (нет в списке -- не существует) как раз стоит поддерживать. Что, учитывая редкость изменений, несложно, и из-за низкого спроса срочности не требует.

Comment: Я изначально хотел оставить ссылку на список всех Stack Overflow, это был бы оптимальный вариант, но похоже что отдельной страницы с таким списком не существует.

Comment: Список можно получить фильтрацией в [верхнем баре](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308743/339911), но не знаю, можно ли на это как-то ссылку сделать. В крайнем случае, можно организовать вопрос/ответ с перечнем локализованных сайтов SO, если такового ещё никто не сделал где либо.

Comment: @alexolut ситуация осложняется ещё и тем, что у японского SO нет слов Stack Overflow в названии.

Comment: @D-side зато есть без пробела :) Посмотрите по ссылке, что я привёл.

Comment: @alexolut хм... фильтр явно по URL'ам. Умно :)