# Нужен ли перевод причины закрытия за вопрос на английском?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Было, хм, [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4091/15479).

Тогда утверждалось:

> Согласно моим субъективным наблюдениям, практически все авторы таких
>   вопросов прекрасно понимают русский язык

Я сейчас часто наблюдаю вопросы на английском от авторов, судя по профилю которых, в русском они не бум-бум.

По сему, снова поднимаю вопросы:

1. Может текст комментария по этой причине закрытия писать на английском?
2. На каком языке писать в комментариях? Или сразу на двух? А то человек пишет на английском, ему там что-то советуют на русском.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переформулировать тревогу о вопросе не на русском языке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7090/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: @AK немного не то, там обсуждение формулировки на русском.

Comment: По второму вопросу - обычно пишу на двух.

Comment: Если они не бум-бум, то как они пробрались сквозь тернии русифицированного интерфейса, чтобы задать вопрос?

Comment: Хотя, браузер же может переводить, я так на японский заходил почитать)

Comment: @vp_arth это у них спрашивать надо (: Я так понимаю, большая часть из них приходит с en SO, а расположение кнопок одинаковое.

Comment: @Suvitruf но как они вообще попали на руСО?

Comment: @PavelMayorov у них там банер сверху висит типо "Задайте вопрос на ru SO"

Comment: @Suvitruf а за каким фигом этот баннер показывается тем кто в русском не бум-бум? И, кстати, как они поняли что на этом баннере написано?

Answer (score 1):

Язык может быть не обязательно английским. И не смотря на то, что в текущей причине закрытия предлагается воспользоваться enSO (выделено мной)

> Вопрос закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь **Stack Overflow на английском**.

как наиболее вероятным кандидатом (вряд ли тут будут актуальны ptSO, esSO или jaSO) перевод на английский, по моему мнению, не нужен. Просто потому, что для того, чтобы задать вопрос уже надо пройти через русскоязычный интерфейс из кнопок с русскими названияи  "Задать вопрос", "Проверить ваш вопрос" и остальных обвязок, наполненных русским языком. А это значит, что задающий уже как-то понял смысл всего его, но, может быть, предположил, что это основано на языковых предпочтениях его браузера или ещё чего. Я лично периодически встречаю англоязычные сайты, где некоторые интерфейсные кнопки проскакивают на русском.

Вердикт: перевод не нужен.