# Некорректный перевод причины закрытия вопроса о на нерусском языке

Tags: дефект, локализация, причины-закрытия

При тревоге на вопросе одна из причин выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Считаю данную причину некорректной, так как решение о закрытии вопроса принимается коллективно, и не может быть тревоги с фразой "вопрос закрыт", ибо вопрос не закрыт (пока).

Такой причины нет на оригинальном сайте StackOverflow, однако она присутствует на португальском, испанском и японском его версиях:

```
Португальский:
Essa pergunta não pertence ao site porque não está em Português. Poderá ser reaberta se for traduzida.
~~
Данный вопрос не вне темы сайта, так как он не на португальском. Вопрос может быть переведен и переоткрыт.
```

```
Испанский:
La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.
~~
Вопрос написан на языке, отличном от официального языка этого сайта, то есть испанского.
```

```
Японский:
当サイト (ja.stackoverflow.com) は Stack Overflow (stackoverflow.com) とは独立して日本語の質問を扱うサイトとして運営されています。詳しくは、 Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？ をご覧ください。この質問を日本語に編集していただければ、引き続きこのサイトで扱うことができます。英語で質問をするには、Stack Overflow へ新しく質問を投稿する必要があります。
~~
[С этим не справился ни я, ни переводчик, Но суть та же, даже ссылка на вопрос про английский есть.]
```

Как видим на всех остальных сайтах сети такая причина имеет более формальный вид.
Предлагаю исправить перевод на подобный:

```
Данный вопрос следует закрыть, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос или воспользуйтесь сайтом Stack Overflow для другого языка.
```

или подобный:

```
Данный вопрос не соответствует теме сайта Stack Overflow на русском, так как его официальным языком является русский.
```

Хочу также отметить, что подобная тема уже поднималась на Stack Overflow на русском [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7090/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5), косвенно подобная тема зацеплялась [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5509/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8c) и  [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8410/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5). И в первом случае вроде бы даже было много согласий от довольно рейтинговых участников ([1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/337540/victor-vosmottor), [2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/193683/denis)), что действительно нужно заменять, исправлять, однако сейчас, на удивление, мы имеем то же, что и год с лишним назад.

Хотелось бы поднять эту тему еще раз, так как фраза `Вопрос закрыт` в списке ПРИЧИН для закрытия вопроса это мягко говоря странно, а грубо говоря совершеннейший нелогичный бред.

Comment: @Danis а разве метка "Перевод содержимого" не подходит?

Comment: `Для перевода интерфейса сайта и статей справки используйте метку [локализация] вместо этой.`

Comment: Мне не кажется, что это имеет какое-то значение . В конце концов когда/если вопрос закроют это то, что будет написано в плашке сверху...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor А если не закроют? Вы считаете правильной фразу "Вопрос закрыт", когда вопрос открыт? А что там будет написано, когда вопрос будет закрыт - так это другое далекое дело.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Вы внимательно читали мое предложение? Я упоминал, что такая тема уже упоминалась, но осталась без изменений. Я ее поднял снова, так как 2 года назад к единому мнению не пришли и причину не изменили.

Comment: @МаксимФисман срок давности не важен здесь, к сожалению. Если суть та же, и подходят те же самые ответы, то это дубликат. Своей публикацией вы освежили интерес к проблеме, ваш вопрос, даже будучи закрыт как «дубликат» всё равно останется на сайте. Но это не повод размазывать ответы по разным (с точки зрения ссылок) и одновременно одинаковым (по сути) вопросам.